# How do I make the bot say something only when the user's message ends with a question mark?

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.command(aliases=["ques", "q", "8ball", "QUES", "Q", "8BALL"])
async def question(ctx):
    answer = "yes", "no", "idk"
    final_answer = random.choice(answer)

    await ctx.send("Please ask a yes or no question")
    msg = await client.wait_for("message")

    if ctx.content.endswith("?"):
        await ctx.send(final_answer)
    else:
        await ctx.send("That's not a question!")
```

So I wanna add a function to my discord bot for 8ball. but I want the bot to find out whether the text sent is a question or not. I'm using the endswith attribute here but it shows

````
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'content'```
````

Comment: Did you mean `if msg.endswith("?"):`?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?
Specifically, where did you output a trace of `ctx.content`?

Comment: do i have to write it that way cause i thought i had to use context. ill try that and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the error pretty much speaks for itself, `Context` doesn't have the `content` attribute. You defined `msg` in `await client.wait_for(...)`, you should use that variable instead of `ctx`

```py
@client.command(aliases=["ques", "q", "8ball", "QUES", "Q", "8BALL"])
async def question(ctx):
    answer = "yes", "no", "idk"
    final_answer = random.choice(answer)

    await ctx.send("Please ask a yes or no question")
    msg = await client.wait_for("message")

    if msg.content.endswith("?"):
        await ctx.send(final_answer)
    else:
        await ctx.send("That's not a question!")
```

Comment: `msg.content.endswith`, like in the code I wrote

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank You so much! I am happy I joined stack overflow!!!

Comment: No worries! Remember to accept the answer if it helped (tick on the left upper side of the answer)